How to send image inside quotation in telegram?
Hello i need to make sending image in telegram bot like on image
I have qr code image with link, i want to know how to place image inside quotation.
I tried to make with sendPhoto, but it looks like default image sending with captions

As I can see, it's not actually the sendPhoto method. It's just the sendMessage method to send a normal text message. The quoted image is actually the Link Preview.
You can POST to sendMessage with something like the following data to achieve this:
{
    "chat_id": 123456,
    "text": "Hello World",
    "link_preview_options": {
        "url": "https://URL_TO_IMAGE_TO_BE_SHOWN.jpg"
    }
}

Or you can do it by GET method by calling the following URL:
https://api.telegram.org/<BOT_TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=<CHAT_ID>&text=Hello+World&link_preview_options={%22url%22:%22<IMAGE_TO_BE_SHOWN.jpg>%22}

Make sure to replace the <BOT_TOKEN>, <CHAT_ID>, and <IMAGE_TO_BE_SHOWN.jpg> with appropriate data.
Hope this helps!

Yeah thanks, its working. I just pasted a link and its looks like on image!
